# Get the parent node of an HTML block with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parent, execcommand

I have an HTML block:

```
<div style="text-align:left">
    <span>aaaaa</span>
    <span>bbbbb</span>
    <span>ccccc</span>
    <span>ddddd</span>
</div>
```

In my editor when I try to select this div I get only the spans selected but not the div. So my selection with this code is:

```
 sel = parent.document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.getSelection();
 var range = sel.getRangeAt (0);
 var docFragment = range.cloneContents ();
 var tmpDiv = document.createElement ("div");
 tmpDiv.appendChild (docFragment);
 selHTML = tmpDiv.innerHTML;
```

so when I alert(selHTML) I get the code with the spans I wrote in the begging. But this HTML is wrapped by a div. 
How can I get this div ?

I want that because I want to make a manually execCommand for aligment. Because in firefox I use the execCommand but is not working properly, as the selection is not done properly, and instead of change the text-align in the div I already have, it adds a new div.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `selHTML = tmpDiv.parentNode.innerHTML`?

Comment: If I alert that I get "tmpDiv.parentNode is null"

Comment: correct. It hasn't been appended to anything yet.  Use outerHTML to get all the HTML of the div including the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want outerHTML, which should include the div and all of its contents.

```
selHTML = tmpDiv.outerHTML;
```

Or

```
sel = parent.document.getElementById('frame')
  .contentWindow.document.getSelection();  

var range = sel.getRangeAt (0);  
var docFragment = range.cloneContents();  
var tmpDiv1 = document.createElement("div"); 
var tmpDiv2 = document.createElement('div'); 
tmpDiv2.appendChild (docFragment); 
tmpDiv1.appendChild(tmpDiv2); 
selHTML = tmpDiv1.innerHTML;
```

Comment: yes but this one just give me the temporary div and all the content.I do not really want the whole content. I just want to check if these spans are wrapped already by a div with text-align.

Comment: note that in Firefox `outerHTML` is available only in the latest Firefox versions: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92264

Comment: I suppose you'll have to append the div element to another object and get innerHTML of that one.

Comment: ok this seems to work, but I have to use outerHTML instead of innerHTML.

Comment: @novellino - Now I'm lost... is that a question?  I provided two solutions, 1 uses outerHTML and 1 that uses innerHTML.

Comment: not clear yet. "want to check if these spans are wrapped already by a div with text-align" . that information can be retrieved by `tmpDiv1.appendChild(tmpDiv2); 
selHTML = tmpDiv1.innerHTML;   
console.log(selHTML.style.cssText) //this works in chrome, not sure if it works on FF`

Comment: The one that works for me is the second solution but using outerHTML instead of innerHTML.

Comment: @novellino - gotcha. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `setHTML.parentNode` ?

Comment: Yes but when I alert it I get "undefined"

Comment: that's because selHTML is a string. I think you meant tmpDiv.parent.  However, since tmpDiv hasn't been appended to anything yet, .parent will be null.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox you can use [commonAncestorContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.commonAncestorContainer) property of a range. So in your case:

```
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var container = range.commonAncestorContainer;

if (container && container.tagName === "div" && container.style.textAlign) {
    // it's a div tag with an inline style text-align prop

    // you can also modify the container directly:
    container.style.textAlign = "center";
}
```